# Connection hangs after time of inactivity

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring, jdbc

In my application, Spring manages connection pool for database access. Hibernate uses these connections for its queries. At first glance, I have no problems with the pool: it works correctly with concurrent clients and a pool with only one connection. I can execute a lot of queries, so I think that I (or Spring) don't leave open connections.

My problem appears after some time of inactivity (sometimes 30 minutes, sometimes more than 2 hours). Then, when Hibernate does some search, it lasts too much. Setting log4j level to TRACE, I get this logs:

```
...
18:27:01 DEBUG nsactionSynchronizationManager  - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@99abd7] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@7d2897] bound to thread [http-8080-Processor24]
18:27:01 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager     - Found thread-bound Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@8878cd] for Hibernate transaction
18:27:01 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager     - Using transaction object [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager$HibernateTransactionObject@1b2ffee]
18:27:01 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager     - Creating new transaction with name [com.acjoventut.service.GenericManager.findByExample]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
18:27:01 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager     - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@8878cd]
18:27:01 TRACE SessionImpl                     - setting flush mode to: AUTO
18:27:01 DEBUG JDBCTransaction                 - begin
18:27:01 DEBUG ConnectionManager               - opening JDBC connection
```

Here it gets frozen for about 2 - 10 minutes. But then continues:

```
18:30:11 DEBUG JDBCTransaction                 - current autocommit status: true
18:30:11 DEBUG JDBCTransaction                 - disabling autocommit
18:30:11 TRACE JDBCContext                     - after transaction begin
18:30:11 DEBUG HibernateTransactionManager     - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [jdbc:oracle:thin:@212.31.39.50:30998:orcl, UserName=DEVELOP, Oracle JDBC driver]
18:30:11 DEBUG nsactionSynchronizationManager  - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@843a9d] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@7745fd] to thread [http-8080-Processor24]
18:30:11 DEBUG nsactionSynchronizationManager  - Initializing transaction synchronization
...
```

After that, it works with no problems, until another period of inactivity. IMHO, it seems like connection pool returns an invalid/closed connection, and when Hibernate realizes that, ask another connection to the pool.

I don't know how can I solve this problem or things I can do for delimiting it. Any help achieving this will be appreciate.

Thanks.

**EDIT: Well, it finally was due a firewall rule. Database detects the connection is lost, but pool (dbcp or c3p0) not. So, it tries to query the database with no success. What is still strange for me is that timeout period is very variable. Maybe the rule is specially strange or firewall doesn't work correctly. Anyway, I have no access to that machine and I can only wait for an explanation. :(**

Comment: How did you identify if this was a firewall issue? I'm facing a similar issue where dbcp hangs indefinitely on my Spring Batch transaction and never returns back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had problems like this before when the database is on a seperate box and there's a firewall in between which is set to timeout idle connections.

In some circumstances the firewall cuts off the connection in such a way that the JDBC end doesn't detect, and attempting to use it results in an indefinite block.

In my case it was a custom connection pool which sent a test query down the connection before returning it from the pool. I configured this test query to have a timeout (using Statement.setQueryTimeout) so that it didn't block indefinitely.

Comment: I am not sure why you would use a custom pool to only send a test query. A little decent connection pool and/or container managed datasource is already capable of this. So does for example DBCP and Tomcat JNDI. Refer the config documentation using under each the keyword `validationQuery`.

Comment: This was in a project (a long long time ago) that used a bespoke connection pool and was in the section of code that did indeed do a similar thing to validationQuery in DBCP.

Comment: You're right. It seems that the problem is some firewall rule out of my control. I think that the best solutions would be change firewall behaviour. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the config of your pool implementation. Usually, it's [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) which has [a timeout](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html) for each connection after it will close it.

In your code, you shouldn't keep connections around. Get one, use it, close it immediately. The pool will make sure that this doesn't cost too much.

Comment: Spring manages my connections, so I'm not the one who must explicitely call Connection.close(). Am I? As you say, I'm using org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource, with destroy-method="close". I'll research about it.

Comment: There are two other sources of trouble: There might be a firewall between you and the database server (but a 2h timeout on idle TCP connections is a bit short). Or your database is configured to close idle connections after some time. See the other config options of DBCP to check for dead connections and for pinging the DB in regular intervals to keep the pipe open.

Comment: As for close: No, you shouldn't close it but you should end the transaction (which will make Spring see that the connection can be returned to the pool).

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve idle time out issue is to have dual connection pools, one is active and other one is standby (no connections created yet). Have a timer with trigger time much less than FIREWALL_IDLE_TIMEOUT and switch between connection pools. I tried this and ITS WORKING.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add some parameters in your DataSource:

more important add testOnBorrow and validationQuery

Answer (score 1):

We solved problem with similar symptoms which also turned out to be caused by a firewall.

We were able to work around the problem by changing the testWhileIdle connection pool property which prevents the connection from going idle and from the firewall shutting down the connection. See [Apache commons dbcp BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html). Here is an exert from the configuration file, persistentce-context.xml that fixed the problem:

```
<property name="testWhileIdle">
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis">
  <value>600000</value>
</property>
<property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis">
  <value>600000</value>
</property>
```

Most likely we only need to add the testWhileIdle (false by default), but added the other two properties for good measure.

In our case, here are some of the logs which we were seeing. Notice in this debug logs, it would take 16 minutes to open the connection before the connection could be used and this is what caused everything to hang. There were no errors which made it hard to track down.

```
09-06-13 @ 16:36:34 [DEBUG] HibernateTransactionManager - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@db17ab]
09-06-13 @ 16:36:34 [DEBUG] ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
09-06-13 @ 16:52:00 [DEBUG] DataSourceUtils - Setting JDBC Connection
09-06-13 @ 16:52:00 [DEBUG] JDBCTransaction - begin
09-06-13 @ 16:52:00 [DEBUG] JDBCTransaction - current autocommit status: true
```