# Sometimes first call returns null

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm very new to hibernate, and I can't find solution for this: I've a simple REST service, apache+tomcat+mysql+hibernate+java, no cache management, so only first level cache, whit a simple query, something like

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

with no records inserted/deleted ecc.

Everything works fine but after a "long" inactivity time, say 1h, if I call the query the result is a null result, if I immediately call again I obtain the result as expected.

I was thinking It was some hibernate issue, something I don't know.
Something to switch on or off... :-)

Can you help me ponting me in the right direction, some link to read.
Thank's.

Comment: What is a "null result"?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose probably `null`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer As a result for the SQL call `SELECT * FROM ...`? This does not make sense.

Comment: if i understand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888923/connection-hangs-after-time-of-inactivity) answer correctly, then it could happen to return `null`

Comment: What's the code?

Comment: Please clarify what is null? Is there a stack trace?